# How to find the linked Microsoft account using only files

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

How can I find out which Microsoft account a Windows user was linked to, if all I have is the files?

My mom's computer broke, and she's getting a new one. Luckily her old hard drive is still fine, so I can easily recover her data.
However, as moms are wont to do, she forgot her Microsoft account name. She has an Office license linked to it, so I'd like to recover it for her new computer. Is there a way to find out what her MS account name was, just by perusing the files on her hard drive?

She appears to also have used her Onedrive. That might have stored that data somewhere accessible.

Comment: Her OneDrive account is the Microsoft Account.  I presume she knows her OneDrive account username and password.  The actual email address might be contained within `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities`, you can mount the registry hive from one installation in read-only state in a working Windows installation.  **There is no magic file that indicates what the Microsoft Account was unless you consider the registry hive to be that file.**

Comment: Her Microsoft Account should be her email address. Log into Microsoft Live with that and see if her password works. The data is in the registry.

Comment: @Ramhound : that did the trick. I was actually able to get the info out of her HKCU\...\IdentityCRL . It had 2 subfolders: one for her personal account, and one for her work.

One of my own e-mail addresses was a password reset e-mail address, so I'm off to the races. Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept.

Comment: @MennovandenHeuvel - Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find out which Microsoft account a Windows user was linked to, if all I have is the files?  Is there a way to find out what her MS account name was, just by perusing the files on her hard drive?

The actual email address is contained within `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities`, you can mount the registry hive from one installation in read-only state in a working Windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's Support article
[You forgot your Microsoft account username](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/you-forgot-your-microsoft-account-username-b2049472-3b8f-27d3-61c6-67a668453f4c):

> If you previously set up security info on your Microsoft account, you
> can use this option to retrieve your username.
>
> 1. [Look up your username](https://account.live.com/username/recover) using your security contact phone number or email address
> 2. **Request a security code** to be sent to the phone number or email you used.
> 3. Enter the code and select **Next**.
> 4. When you see the account you're looking for, select **Sign in**.

I hope that your Mom's phone number (or yours) was entered into her Microsoft account,
or that she still has access to her email.
That's all that she needs in order to recover the account name and then
reset its password.

Comment: I tried this first, but it turned out to be not that helpful: my mom had registered her phone number itself as a Microsoft account, and then not used it at all. All pretty much as expected, really.

Her Office was hidden in a different account which I found in her registry file.